# Golang equivalent of Java's SHA256withRSA

Tags: go, cryptography

Is there any Golang equivalent of Java's `java.security.Signature`'s SHA256withRSA? A couple of research is that I could not simple calculate the SHA256 hash and then signing it with RSA.

Comment: I assume you've seen the built-in [`crypto/rsa`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/) package, so show us what you've tried and we can guide you from there.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I am currently blackbox integration against a third party API, though with this solution the application gives back an invalid signature. I will not need the decryption part I believe, i will just send the base64Enc(encrypted) string to the third party API

Comment: That the java class is named `Signature` should give you a hint that you want RSA   signature methods, not encryption methods.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out if someone stumbled on the same question, here's how it works in Go

```
func main() {
    privateKey := loadPrivateKey()
    h := sha256.New()
    h.Write([]byte(`your message`))
    d := h.Sum(nil)

    signature, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privateKey, crypto.SHA256, d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Signature in byte: %v\n\n", signature)

    encodedSig := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(signature)

    fmt.Printf("Encoded signature: %v\n\n", encodedSig)
}
```